# Any way to have a namespace with an alternative name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces

Using VB.net, I have a namespace which I'd like to rename for the future.  However, I'd also like to keep the old obsolete namespace for a time to ensure backward-compatibility for our consumers for awhile.  **Is there a way in .NET to have two namespaces, one ordinary and one that merely is an alternative name for the other?**

In other words, I would have two namespaces with duplicate classes and modules.  Obviously, I could copy all the code, but I really want to do something like

```
<Obsolete("Use types in namespace MyCompany.Area.ProjectName instead.")>
Namespace MyCompany.WrongArea.WrongProjectName
    Inherits Namespace MyCompany.Area.ProjectName
End Namespace
```

(A C# answer would be nice too, if you have it.)

Comment: Maybe you could use pre-compiler directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say the answer is simply "no".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at something like namespace aliasing.

See: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/34419 for example

Comment: You can't have `.` in the name.

Comment: Aliasing was my first thought as well.

Comment: That merely gives an alternative name in one code file to make coding easier.  I want to provide two namespaces to consumers of my code.